# How to set multiple images on a SWT TreeItem?

Tags: java, swt

I working on an SWT `Tree` where each `TreeItem` needs to have multiple images on it. Right now I am trying to do

```
treeItem.setImage(index, Image)
```

and trying to set multiple `Images` on a single `TreeItem`. But it doesn't seem to work. What is this method about? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen a tree with multiple images on a node. How would it look like?

Comment: @Dan It's a tree with columns, similar to a table.

Comment: I din't know that it is similar to Table until this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see your problem. The following works perfectly for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.NONE);
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);        

    TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
    column1.setText("Column 1");
    column1.setWidth(50);
    TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
    column2.setText("Column 2");
    column2.setWidth(50);
    TreeColumn column3 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
    column3.setText("Column 3");
    column3.setWidth(50);

    Image image = YOUR_IMAGE_HERE;

    TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    item.setImage(0, image);
    item.setImage(1, image);
    item.setImage(2, image);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while(!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not create a TreeColumn and that is the reason why I was not able to set the Image. I was wondering where the index parameter is in the method. Now its lot more clear :)

Comment: @user1623627 You're welcome. In my first try, I forgot them too :)